Does mediate() in r work with a multicategorical predictor?
My data is multilevel (multiple measures for each participant within each condition) with 3 conditions.
DV = continuous; Mediator = continuous; IV = categorical (with 3 conditions: control, condition A, condition B; within-ss).
For the IV, I created dummy variables (A = 0, 1; B = 0, 1; Control = 0, 1) for the analyses.
Does mediate() work with multicategorical predictors? Assuming my model is theoretically sound, is it appropriate to run the following analyses to compute the indirect effects, total effects, direct effects, etc mediation paths of the variables?
I use the "mediation" package for the mediate() command and the "lme4" package to generate the multilevel models.
My analyses are listed below:
Analyses:
library(lme4)
library(mediation)

fit.mediator=lmer(Mediator ~ IV.A + IV.B + (1 | id), data=data1)

summary(fit.mediator)

fit.dv=lmer(DV ~ IV.A + IV.B + Mediator + (1 | id), data=data1)

summary(fit.dv)

summary(mediate(fit.mediator, fit.dv, treat='IV.A', mediator='Mediator'))

summary(mediate(fit.mediator, fit.dv, treat='IV.B', mediator='Mediator'))


You can do it, but you'll need to leave your IV as a factor rather than making it dummy variables yourself.  The modelling functions will deal with that.  Here's an example with he mtcars data:
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)
library(mediation)
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number(), 
         cyl = as.factor(cyl), 
         model = rownames(mtcars), 
         make = gsub("([A-Za-z]*) .*", "\\1", model))

m1 <- lmer(hp ~ cyl + (1|make), data=mtcars)
m2 <- lmer(qsec ~ hp + cyl + (1|make), data=mtcars)
m <- mediate(m1, m2, treat="cyl", mediator = "hp", control.value="4", treat.val="8")
summary(m)
#> 
#> Causal Mediation Analysis 
#> 
#> Quasi-Bayesian Confidence Intervals
#> 
#> Mediator Groups: make 
#> 
#> Outcome Groups: make 
#> 
#> Output Based on Overall Averages Across Groups 
#> 
#>                Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
#> ACME             -1.792       -3.145        -0.45   0.008 ** 
#> ADE              -0.463       -2.319         1.43   0.604    
#> Total Effect     -2.255       -3.353        -1.27  <2e-16 ***
#> Prop. Mediated    0.808        0.194         1.92   0.008 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Sample Size Used: 32 
#> 
#> 
#> Simulations: 1000

Created on 2024-12-18 with reprex v2.1.0
In the example above, I used 4 as the control and 8 as the treatment.  If your IV has three levels, you may have to do this multiple times to get the effects of moving from each value to each other value.
